# Program should continue working when file is in folder

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

Let's say I have a program that moves files from folder `A` to folder `B` and then sends them via jms.
That part works fine, but it still tries to move files, when no more files are there. Atm I got a work around, that  the  connection closes if no files are there, but as it says in the title, the program should stop, or rather 'idle' until a file *is* in the folder a and then continue moving and sending those folders. I have no idea if that is even doable in Java at all, so please some help, would appreciate it :)
My code for the work around:

```
//dir is the "folder a" path
if (dir.listFiles().length == 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60000);
                if (dir.listFiles().length == 0) {
                    session.close();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on *nix, there's always current directory ('.') and parent directory ('..') which I believe will always make the length > 0.

On Windows, the same directories exist, but not sure if they are returned, there less intrusive in Windows.

And listFiles() returns anything that's in the directory as a File, which may include other directories.  You might need to create a file filter if you truly just want files.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do cannot be done in one brief section of code.  I created an open source project called [Universal File Mover](http://www.capitalware.com/ufm_overview.html) (UFM).  One of its function is to 'watch' for files and then do something with them.  i.e. Send them via MQ or ftp or sftp or http or any other UFM action.

Go download the source code for UFM and pull out the 'biz.capitalware.ufm.watch' package which handles watching directories or particular files.

Comment: so there is no easy way to watch for files incoming? oh and it would be so nice to mention in what action or what so ever the wtach is established :) thank you

Comment: Seriously??  You can't download the code OR read the Table of Contents of the manual and notice an Action called 'Watch'.  Seriously!!  Someone gives everything and you still wine that you can't be bothered to do the tiniest amount of work. OMG.